# How to customize space between letters

Tags: java, format

When I was writing the code, **I got a question that how to customize the space between letters?**

Here is my code:

The code: **System.out.print('\t');** makes the space between letters is one **tab**.
The output of the follow code is like:

1 ### A ### B ### C ### D
2 ### A ### B ### C ### D
3 ### A ### B ### C ### D
4 ### A ### B ### C ### D
5 ### A ### B ### C ### D
6 ### A ### B ### C ### D
7 ### A ### B ### C ### D

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    char[][] seat = new char[7][5];

    for (int row=0; row<7; row++){
        seat[row][0] = (char)('1' + row);
        }

    for (int row=0; row<7; row++){
        for (int col=1; col<5; col++){
            seat[row][col] = (char)('A'+ col-1);
        }
    }

    for (int row=0; row<7; row++){
        for (int col=0; col<5; col++){
            System.out.print(seat[row][col]);
            System.out.print('\t');
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Comment: I'm failing to see a question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
         ...
    for (int row=0; row<7; row++){
        for (int col=0; col<5; col++){
            System.out.printf("%-8s", seat[row][col]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
         ...
```

output

```
1       A       B       C       D       
2       A       B       C       D       
3       A       B       C       D       
4       A       B       C       D       
5       A       B       C       D       
6       A       B       C       D       
7       A       B       C       D
```

see java.util.Formatter API to know more about formatting options

Answer (score 0):

take a `string` and replace characters to customize it and put it in your Sop statement like this `System.out.print(chars);`  instead of `System.out.print("\t");`

rewrite your code like this

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    char[][] seat = new char[7][5];
    String chars = "###";
    for (int row=0; row<7; row++){
        seat[row][0] = (char)('1' + row);
        }

    for (int row=0; row<7; row++){
        for (int col=1; col<5; col++){
            seat[row][col] = (char)('A'+ col-1);
        }
    }

    for (int row=0; row<7; row++){
        for (int col=0; col<5; col++){
            System.out.print(seat[row][col]);
            System.out.print(chars);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that's what he's asking, and without using a fixed width font I doubt you're going to get the result you think (in any other scenario).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String.format(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29), maybe that helps (if I understood your question).